# Returning value from a method having return type Task

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I am probably missing out something here. Syntax is incorrect.

```
static Task<int> MathOperation(int number)
{
    //return new Task(new Func(TestMethod(number)));
}

static int LongRunningMethod(int number)
{
    // some long running operation
}
```

How to code the `return` statement of `MathOperation` ?

> *I am getting this error: Using the generic type 'System.Func' requires 1 type arguments.*

Comment: It depends on what you're actually trying to do. I *suspect* you want `Task.Run`... is the aim to do `LongRunningMethod` in a separate task, in the background? Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Exactly. I want that method to run in a background thread :

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). You should avoid using `new Task` as it returns a "Cold Task" which means that the `Task` has to be started using `Start()`. Use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
static Task<int> MathOperation(int number)
{
    return Task.Run(() => TestMethod(number));
}
```

Comment: so, this task starts running immediately at a `background thread` (another thread) ?

Comment: Yes it does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you. Looking exactly for that. :)